# UICollectionview cellForItemAtIndexPath not getting called when reload in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've been working my apps to run on iOS 8 and trying to consume data from the restful API. After getting response from the webservice I'm trying to reload the collectionview from the delegate method.I get the valid numeric count as 5 from my array for numberOfItemsInSection but cellForItemAtIndexPath not getting called.

*I see in one scenario, If I hardcode the numberOfItemsInSection return count as 5 then cellForItemAtIndexPath is perfectly called while reload.*

Here is my code snippet:

```
#pragma mark = UICollectionViewDataSource
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
     return 1; 
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [offerModel.arrayOffers count]; 
}

- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
     NSString *identifier = @"OfferCell";

     static BOOL nibMyCellloaded = NO;

     if(!nibMyCellloaded){
         UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:identifier bundle: nil];
         [offerCollectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
         nibMyCellloaded = YES;
     }

   OfferCell* cell = (OfferCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier
 forIndexPath:indexPath]; //     // Commented binding values return
 cell; 
}

- (void)updateOfferList{
     [offerCollectionView reloadData]; 
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
     [offerCollectionView registerClass:[OfferCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"OfferCell"];

     // set up delegates
     self.offerCollectionView.delegate = self;
     self.offerCollectionView.dataSource = self;   
}
```

Please help me on this. Quick replies are most appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why not edit your question to show your code for `numberOfItemsInSection:`?

Comment: Are you sure about "I get the valid numeric count as 5 from my array for numberOfItemsInSection"? How do you know?

Comment: I did debug the array count and print the count as well, initially when view is loading count prints "0" and after received objects from API the count print and returns "5". I'm sure about it.

Comment: Any update on this issue from any expert ?

Comment: are you sure that your collectoinView is of type offercollectionview?

and further: you should be setting the delegate on your iboutlet, os if collectionView is your actual UI item, then you should be calling self.collectoinView.reloadData

Comment: sorry, before I found solution I had updated to offerCollectionView instead of all self.collectionView.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found an answer for my blocker. I just Reloading some items didn't work for me using reload data. Since CV default flow layout does some internal operation itself to reload data when we forced, In my case, I'm using customviewlayout here **layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath** and **layoutAttributesForElementsInRect** called only when the section gets loaded. Here it works because the collectionView has just one section, I've reloaded specific section would make contents correctly reloaded in the CV.

At my API handler delegate method placed the below code snippet,

```
[self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];                 
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]` before reloading the data? Also, make sure you're on the main thread when you call reload data. If you're not on the UI thread the CollectionView will not reload as expected.

Comment: Yes, I did the same what you recommended but was not helpful for me.